# Java...am i using 'this' correctly?

Tags: java

Running into problems and I'm wondering if I'm using `this` correctly.

Is this ok?

```
public person{
.
.
.
    public void setmother(person mom){
        mom.addchild(this);
    }
```

I'm created a `personb` class. Inside setmother, I want to use a method that adds children to the class. I want to add the current instance of the class to the array of children in the mom instance of the class.

I don't even know if I have the lingo down...hopefully someone understands what I'm trying to do!

Comment: There's no `self` keyword in java. I assume you mean `this`. Without seeing more of your class, we have no idea. Not to mention `public person{` is a syntax error.

Comment: You should take another look at the [coding style conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for Java. It costs you nothing to use them and makes it easier for others to grok your code.

Comment: It's called `this`. Stick to it, the Python guys dislike hearing of `this` as well ;) As for the question... very vague and basic. At the very least: How does `.addchild` look like?

Answer (score 6):

Your code looks fine as it stands, i.e. you are using "this" correctly.

It's probably a good idea to also set a field that points from the child to the mother - otherwise it can be hard to implement a corresponding "getMother" method in the future, i.e. something like:

```
public class Person {
    private Person mother;
.
.
.
    public void setMother(Person mom){
        mom.addChild(this);
        mother=mom;
    }
.
.
}
```

The other minor thing I would change is the naming convention in order to be more in line with usual Java style:

- person => Person (class names start with capitals)
- setmother => setMother (method names start with lowercase but use capitals for following words)
- addchild => addChild

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using `this` correctly, apart from it not being called "self", and regardless of the other syntax errors in the above code.